# Copy and Pasting Images in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to copy and paste a .ppm image, but I keep getting a black square instead of a smaller version of the copied image. The image that I am originally opening is a blue and white flag, and once I try to copy and paste the image and save it as a new file name, it is just a black square. I am not sure if I am missing a certain function, or if I am just having a simple error in my code. Thanks!

Code:

```
    from image import ImagePPM

def getImage():
    filename = input("What is the name of your image file?")
    img = ImagePPM.open(filename)
    return ImagePPM.open(filename)


def copyImage():
    filename = input("What is the image file name again?")
    img = ImagePPM.open(filename) 
    width, height = img.size
    u1width = int(input("What is the upper left width coordinate?"))
    ulheight = int(input("What is the upper left height?"))
    lrwidth = int(input("What is the lower right width?"))
    lrheight = int(input("What is the lower right height coordinate?"))
    copyImage = ImagePPM.new( (width, height))
    for w in range(width//2):
        for h in range(height//2):
            r, g, b = img.getpixel( (w,h) )
            copyImage.putpixel( (w,h), (r,g,b) )
    return copyImage

def saveImage():
    filename = input("Provide a filename to save your image in.")
    img = ImagePPM.open(filename)
    img.save(filename)
    print("Image saved")

def main():
    getImage()
    copyImage()
    saveImage()

main()
```

Output:

```
    What is the name of your image file?xray.ppm
What is the image file name again?xray.ppm
What is the upper left width coordinate?45
What is the upper left height?45
What is the lower right width?45
What is the lower right height coordinate?45
Provide a filename to save your image in.clipboard.ppm
Image saved
```

Comment: `saveImage` looks strange to me. You're opening an image, and then saving that image to that image's filename? Shouldn't you be doing something with the image returned by `copyImage`?

Comment: It seems like you don't understand how `return` works. You might want to reread the docs on how functions work.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but I think it's closer to what you want (using parameters in your function calls) ...

```
from image import ImagePPM

def getImage():
    filename = input("What is the name of your image file?")
    img = ImagePPM.open(filename)
    return img


def copyImage(start_image):
    width, height = start_image.size
    u1width = int(input("What is the upper left width coordinate?"))
    ulheight = int(input("What is the upper left height?"))
    lrwidth = int(input("What is the lower right width?"))
    lrheight = int(input("What is the lower right height coordinate?"))
    copyImage = ImagePPM.new( (width, height))
    for w in range(width//2):
        for h in range(height//2):
            r, g, b = start_image.getpixel( (w,h) )
            copyImage.putpixel( (w,h), (r,g,b) )
    return copyImage

def saveImage(new_image):
    filename = input("Provide a filename to save your image in.")
    new_image.save(filename)
    print("Image saved")

def main():
    start_image = getImage()
    new_image = copyImage(start_image)
    saveImage(new_image)

main()
```